# Series sum of sin log and cos log

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, summation, analytic-number-theory, trigonometric-series

I was solving a series based question and I am now totally confused on how to proceed further to find the  **analytical** values of $a$ and $b$ (where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$) such that:

$$
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\cos(b \ln(k))}{k^a} = 1
$$

and

$$
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\sin(b \ln(k))}{k^a} = 0
$$

where $\ln x$ is the natural logarithm.

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This looks like an awful lot of things should just cancel out.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to simplify it as much as I can and have now edited the equations.

Comment: No, but I need an exact solution (if possible)

Comment: I was trying to find out the zeros of Dirichlet eta function and after some calculations I reached this pair of equations. Now I dont know how to proceed further

Comment: I don't think this is going to go anywhere. While the statement is certainly true of any $\eta(a + i b) = 0$ with $a > 0$, this doesn't seem like a good way to find such points.

Comment: @eyeballfrog then should I drop the idea to find out the zeros using this approach? And if yes then could you please guide me to find it using some other approach (if there exists any). Thanks :)

Comment: Wikipedia has [a decent rundown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) of the case where $a = 1$. The remaining zeros of the $\eta$ function are the same as the zeros of the $\zeta$ function--a rather longstanding problem in mathematics.

Comment: @ujjwal Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I  really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 4):

We begin with the equations in the posted question

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\sin(b\log(n))}{n^a}=0\tag1$$

and

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cos(b\log(n))}{n^a}=1\tag2$$

Multiplying $(1)$ by $i$ and subtracting from $(2)$, we find that the pair of equations $(1)$ and $(2)$  are equivalent to the equation

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^z}=0\tag3$$

where $z=a+ib$.

The series on the left-hand side of $(3)$ is a representation of the Dirichlet Eta Function, $\eta(z)$, for $\text{Re}(z)>0$.  Therefore, the posted question implicitly asks to find the zeros of the Eta function in the right-half plane.

---

To proceed, we note the relationship

$$\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^z}}_{\eta(z), \text{Re}(z)>0}=(1-2^{1-z})\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^z}}_{\zeta(z),\text{Re}(z)>1}\tag4$$

where the series on the right-hand side of $(4)$ is a representation of the Riemann Zeta function, $\zeta(z)$, for $\text{Re}(z)>1$.

---

---

> **ASIDE:**
>
> 1. I showed in [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897433/convergence-of-zetas-on-res-1/1897815#1897815) and [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909006/does-sum-k-1-infty-frac1kn-converge-for-ren-1-imn-ne0/1909271#1909271) that the series representation for $\zeta(z)$ in $(4)$ diverges for $\text{Re}(z)\le 1$.
> 2. We can extend the definition of $\zeta(z)$ to the right-half plane by rewriting $(4)$ as
>
> $$\zeta(z)=(1-2^{1-z})^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^z}\tag5$$
>
> for $\text{Re}(z)>0$.  I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4149739/euler-constant-as-limit-of-zeta-function/4149885#4149885) that from $(5)$ we can write
>
> $$\zeta(z)=\frac1{z-1}+\gamma +O(z-1)$$
>
> which explicitly shows that $\zeta(z)$ has a simple pole at $z=1$ with residue $1$.

---

---

It is easy to see from $(5)$ that zeros of $1-2^{1-z}$ are also zeros of $\eta(z)$ unless they are also poles of $\zeta(z)$.  Therefore, we find that the zeros of $\eta(z)$, as represented by the series in $(3)$, include the points $z_k$ where

$$z_k=1+i\frac{2\pi k}{\log(2)}$$

for $k\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$.

Inasmuch as the zeros of the Zeta function lie in the region $0<\text{Re}(z)<1$, the Dirichlet Eta function has no zeros on the half plane $\text{Re}(z)>1$.  It had been conjectured (The Riemann Hypothesis, 1859) that all of the zeros of $\zeta(z)$ are located at even negative integers (the trivial zeros) and at complex numbers with real part equal to $1/2$.  This conjecture remains unproven at the time of this post.  If this conjecture is true, then all other zeros of $\eta(z)$ as represented by the series in $(3)$ are located at points $z=\frac12+ib$.

---

---

**ZEROS OF THE ETA FUNCTION**

The Eta function can be analytically continued to the left-half plane through the relationship in $(5)$ (i.e., $\eta(z)=(1-2^{1-z})\zeta(z)$) with the Zeta function and the analytic continuation of the Riemann Zeta function through the functional equation

$$\zeta(z)=2^z\pi^{z-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)\Gamma(1-z)\zeta(1-z)\tag6$$

Note from $(6)$ that $\zeta(z)$ has zeros at the negative even integers.  These are the so-called trivial zeros of $\zeta(z)$.  So, we see that the zeros of $\eta(z)$ include the points

$$z_k=\begin{cases}1+i\frac{2k\pi}{\log(2)}&,k\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}\\\\
2k&,k\in \mathbb{Z_{<0}}
\end{cases}$$

Again, if the Riemann hypothesis is correct, all other zeros of $\eta(z)$ are located at points $z=\frac12+ib$.